# MvcMusicStore Tutorial using MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Though i know one can download the code for MvcMusicStore written using Mvc4.
What I'm wondering about, does anyone know whether there exists a tutorial for MvcMusicStore Mvc4(though same tutorial for Mvc3 is available on the web). I tried googling a lot but without success.

Answer (score 1):

I have a fork here that runs on MVC 4: http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/OdeToCode/mobilemvcmusicstore

Comment: thanks a lot, but it would have been awesome if Jon Galloway provided us with an online copy of the MvcMusicStore tutorial coded using MVC4.